# Связать дочерние записи php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть интернет магазин. 
Я добавляю 2 товара (**Б** и **С**) у товара **А** как рекомендуемые. Я уже написал двустороннюю связь, то есть у товара **Б** и **С** появляется рекомендуемый товар **А**.
В чем вопрос, как связать товары **Б** и **С** между собой, после того как добавил их в рекомендуемые товары товару **А**?

Пока код выглядит так...

```
public function add_related_product($product_id, $related_id, $position=0) {
    $query = $this->db->placehold("INSERT IGNORE INTO __related_products SET product_id=?, related_id=?, position=?", $product_id, $related_id, $position);
    $queryZ = $this->db->placehold("INSERT IGNORE INTO __related_products SET product_id=?, related_id=?, position=?", $related_id, $product_id, $position);
    $this->db->query($query);
    $this->db->query($queryZ);
    return $related_id;
}
```

Comment: Интересно, у Вас `placehold` возвращает строку или некий хитрый объект?

Comment: @vp_arth честно говоря я не знаю, это какая то CMS где попросили допилить такой функционал

Comment: @vp_arth В доке написано что это плейсхолдер для запросов. Пример работы: $query = $db->placehold('SELECT name FROM products WHERE id=?', $id);

Comment: Просто, если он возвращает строку, то это эмуляция плейсхолдеров, которая не гарантирует защиту от инъекций (потому как в базу данные и запрос уходят не раздельно)

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял вопрос:

> Есть связи (A->B), (A->C). Они двунаправленные: есть также (B->A), (C->A).
>   Хотелось бы иметь связи (B->C) и (С->B) на основании вышеприведённых связей.

Мне кажется, что хранить полный граф связанных товаров - не лучшая идея.
Лучше завести сущность "СвязкиТоваров" как списки и пополнять их.
Для структуры выше, это будет одна связка: (Linked#1 -> [A, B, C])

В базе это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
Goods (id, title)
31 A
32 B
33 C
LinkedGoodsList (id[, title])  
1  Linked#1
LinkedGoods (id, list_id, goods_id)
7  1  31
7  1  32
7  1  33
```

Таким образом, вы всегда можете получить список связанных с данным товаров.

Comment: Ну да, вы правы, но к сожалению таков функционал данной CMS и переделывать у меня нет ни времени ни желания. Поэтому я бы хотел в условиях текущей реализации доделать такую функцию